# Why is black box called functional testing when it tests also non functional?

Tags: terminology, standards, theory, functional-testing

This has been bothering me for a while. Security, performance tests etc. are all done typically using the black box approach. But these are nonfunctional,while black box is called functional testing.

Is it because it judges the function and it is just a naming or there is an inconsistency?

References:
Software Engineering by Salleh
Software Engineering and Testing by Gupta, Tayal
Software Engineering by A.A.Puntambekar
Software Testing: a Practical Approach by Sandeep Desai, Abhishek Srivastava

Comment: References? I have never heard before that "functional testing" is an exclusive alias for "black box testing".

Comment: SW testing and Q by Naik, Tripathy. Software Engineering by Salleh, Software Engineering and Testing by Gupta,Tayal. Software Engineering by A.A.Puntambekar.Software Testing : a Practical Approach by Sandeep Desai,Abhishek Srivastava

Comment: @user970996: I guess you get downvotes (not from me) because your original question was not easy to understand, and even now it seems like you expect others to get all that books to understand your question. A short cite (see below) would have made your question clearer for the typical reader.

Comment: functional testing = testing of the functionality = testing how the software performs without investigating/having any idea of/ the source code = black box testing

Comment: my guess is that you're confusing "functional requirement" (such as security and performance requirements) with "functional testing" (high level testing of program functionality, which may include how the program reacts over edge-cases data, under load, etc). They are not related at all even though they both use the term "functional".

Comment: @Lie Ryan You confused functional and non functional. Security, performance are typical non-functional requirements...

Comment: @user970696: you're right, `s/functional/non-functional/`

Comment: @superM: functional testing does mean testing of functionality but it has nothing to do with inability to see the source code. Unit testing is white box technique and you test the functionality as well.

Comment: @user970696: let me rephrase: "functional test" tests both "functional requirements" (e.g. core functionalities) and "non-functional requirements" (e.g. security, performance). Your confusion perhaps stems from that, there is no relation between "functional requirement" and "functional testing" except that they both happen to use the term "functional".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, by a quick google search I found a cite from your first reference:

> white box testing techniques are also called structural testing techniques, whereas black-box testing techniques are also called functional testing techniques

I guess you are referring to that. To my understanding the term "functional testing" is used here in a very broad meaning, just to emphasize the difference to "structural testing". From this point of view, "performance" or "security" are also "functions" of a program, since they can be observed by a black-box execution of the program, without knowing details of the source code.

Using the term "functional" in opposition to "non-functional", however, narrows the meaning down to "core functions" or "domain functions". This is a quite different point of view. So if someone speaks about "functional testing", you have to be careful what he might mean and interpret this in relation to the current context.